# Outputting years with no repeated digits

Tags: beginner, strings, ruby, datetime

I'm working through a course now, and was tasked with the following:

> Write a function, `no_repeats(year_start, year_end)`, which takes a range of years and outputs those years which do not have any repeated digits.
>
> You should probably write a helper function, `no_repeat?(year)` which returns true/false if a single year doesn't have a repeat.

I did not know about each_char yet, so I wrote the following:

```
def no_repeats(year_start, year_end)
  (year_start..year_end).to_a.keep_if {|year| no_repeat?(year)}
end

def no_repeat?(year)
  year_array = year.to_s.split(//)
  year_array == year_array.uniq
end
```

I'm wondering if:

1. there is an easier way to make an array from a string with no spaces
2. there is a way to convert each character in a number to an item in a single array without converting the number to a string first
3. there is a better way to do this problem

This is the model solution for a beginner:

> ```
> def no_repeats(year_start, year_end)
>   no_repeats = []
>   (year_start..year_end).each do |yr|
>     no_repeats << yr if no_repeat?(yr)
>   end
>
>   no_repeats
> end
>
> def no_repeat?(year)
>   chars_seen = []
>   year.to_s.each_char do |char|
>     return false if chars_seen.include?(char)
>     chars_seen << char
>   end
>
>   return true
> end
> ```

I'm also wondering about the advantages and disadvantages of my code compared to the model solution. I kind of get that shorter code is better, and readability matters. I don't know how to test code for time yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model solution they propose is very unidiomatic, your code is far better. I'd just made some minor changes:

- Use `String#chars` instead of `String#split(//)`.
- Use `Enumerable#select?` instead of `Array#keep_if` to avoid modifying data in-place. It's better to work with immutable streams of data (with methods from `Enumerable`).

I'd write:

```
def no_repeats(year_start, year_end)
  (year_start..year_end).select { |year| no_repeat?(year) }
end

def no_repeat?(year)
  year_digits = year.to_s.chars
  year_digits == year_digits.uniq
end
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I see exactly why you changed the variable name from "array" to "digits" and why chars is a clearer method than split. I'm curious why you'd take select over keep_if. Please explain.

Comment: `Array#keep_if` changes the original array in-place. In this particular code that's not a problem, but as a general rule, it's not a good idea, I  guess you've read about Functional Programming. In Ruby you usually work with a functional (immutable) streams of data, using Enumerable methods. https://github.com/tokland/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming